# Does a linear function with time invariance distribute over an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

In general if $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ is linear and time invariant so it is true that

$$f(ax(t) + by(t)) = af(x(t)) + bf(y(t))$$

with $x,y: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $a,b \in \mathbb R$.  Does it follow that

$$f\left(\int_{c}^{d} z(t) dt\right) = \int_{c}^{d} f(z(t)) dt$$

where $c,d \in \mathbb R$? And when $c\to -\infty, d \to \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take the impulse response of $f$ to be $e^{-t}\theta(t)$ and let $z=e^{-t}\theta(t)$. Then

$$f\left(e^{-c}-e^{-d}\right) = e^{-c}-e^{-d}$$

$$\int_c^d f(e^{-t}) dt = \int_c^d \int_0^t e^{-\tau}e^{-(t-\tau)}d\tau dt = (c+1)e^{-c}-(d+1)e^{-d}$$